# How to calculate total column value without query by Laravel or php?

Tags: laravel, count, calculation

[image]Here above I want to Calculate Buying Total and selling Total in the current month . Suppose in November I want to calculate  sell row total , buying row total and buying-selling total count. How Can I do that . Please help...

```
**<table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Quantity (Stock IN)</th>
            <th>Buying Total</th>
            <th>Stock</th>
            <th>Selling Total</th>
            <th>Profit (%)</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>


    <tbody>
        @foreach($product_all as $row)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $row->buying_date}}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->product_name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->stock_in }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->buying_price*$row->stock_in }}</td> *********
            <td>{{ $row->total_stock }}</td>
            
            <td>{{ $row->selling_price*($row->stock_in-$row->total_stock)}}</td> ********
            
            <td>{{ ($row->buying_price*$row->stock_in) - ($row->selling_price*($row->stock_in-$row->total_stock)) }}</td>

        </tr>
       @endforeach
        
    </tbody>

</table>**



<h4 style="color: #ff3939; text-align: center;">November Total Invest : {{ #### }} <span> Sell : {{ #### }}</span></h4>
```

Comment: There are two answers to your question. If anyone of the answer solves your issue in question pls remember to mark as accepted for the benefit of subsequent users especially newbies who get a sense that accepted answer solves the issue in preferred way. If the answers don't solve your issue at least let the answer authors know what error you get or why the answer do not solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do:

First: setting parameters

```
**<table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            ...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php 
$yoursum1 = 0;
$yoursum2 = 0;
        foreach($product_all as $row)
        echo "<tr>
            <td>{{ $row->buying_date}}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->product_name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->stock_in }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->buying_price*$row->stock_in }}</td> *********
            <td>{{ $row->total_stock }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->selling_price*($row->stock_in-$row->total_stock)}}</td> ********
            <td>{{ ($row->buying_price*$row->stock_in) - ($row->selling_price*($row->stock_in-$row->total_stock)) }}</td>

        </tr>"
$yoursum1 += $yourvalue1;
$yoursum2 += $yourvalue2;
       endforeach
            echo "<tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Summary</td>
                <td>{{ $yoursum1}}</td>
                <td>{{ $yoursum2}}</td> *********
                <td>{{ $yoursum3}}</td>
                <td>{{ $yoursum4}}</td> ********
                <td>{{ $yoursum5 }}</td>
    
        </tr>"
        ?>
    </tbody>

</table>**
<h4 style="color: #ff3939; text-align: center;">November Total Invest : {{ #### }} <span> Sell : {{ #### }}</span></h4>
```

Second: using query to calculate and insert one row below

```
    @foreach($product_all as $row)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $row->buying_date}}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->product_name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->stock_in }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->buying_price*$row->stock_in }}</td> *********
            <td>{{ $row->total_stock }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->selling_price*($row->stock_in-$row->total_stock)}}</td> ********
            <td>{{ ($row->buying_price*$row->stock_in) - ($row->selling_price*($row->stock_in-$row->total_stock)) }}</td>
        </tr>
       @endforeach
       <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Summary</td>
            <td>{{ $value1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value2 }}</td> *********
            <td>{{ $value3 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value4 }}</td> ********
            <td>{{ ($value5 }}</td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

IT is advisable to keep calculations and processing out of the views. Controllers are meant to be the files where all calculations and data manipulations should be done.

```php
//Say this is inside the controller method from which the view with data is returned as response

public function index(Request $request)
{
    $product_all = Product::all();

    $groupedByMonth = $product_all->groupBy(function($product) {
       return \Illuminate\Support\Carbon::parse($product->date)->format('m');
    });

    $totals = (object) [
        'buying' => $groupedByMonth->map(function($month){
             return $month->sum('buying_total');
        }),
        'selling' => $groupedByMonth->map(function($month){
             return $month->sum('selling_total');
        }),
    ];

    //Pass $totals to the view where it can be accessed as $totals->buying
}
```

As such the calculation/manipulation can be done in blade view between `@php @endphp`